# How to just update the timestamp in duplicate rows while storing the original time stamp?

Tags: python, mysql, date, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a python script the scrapes a website and inserts values into a MySQL database.  The script continuously scrapes a constantly updating website on a sleep delayed loop.  Right now there are 5 columns of values for example (dog, cat, mouse, lizard, snake) that are scraped from the website and the 6 column is a timestamp that is added when the row is inserted into the database by the python script.  I do not want to insert duplicate rows but I would like to retain the original timestamp as well as the updated timestamp if there is a duplicate.  An important metric for the database users is when this row was first found as well as if it is still available on the website that is being scraped.

For example: lets say the script inserted (beagle, calico, white mouse, gecko, python) at 2:30PM.  When the loop runs again in a half-hour it finds the same row but at a new timestamp of 3:00PM.  What would be the best way to not insert a duplicate record but illustrate the time difference of 30 minutes between when the row was first found and when it was last found? I am fairly decent at Python but have very little MySQL experience so perhaps I need a little help here. Do you think I should put this functionality in at the script side or on the database side through a SQL query?  If so how can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Make a column unique, then use INSERT on ERROR UPDATE to add the latest time

Comment: If your first timestamp field `date_insert`, you could add another field `date_update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

- having two different timestamp columns: on that stores the date when the record was created, the other to store the last modified date. This can be easily done in MySQL with default values, so you don’t need to manage these columns from your application code
- creating a unique (or primary key) constraint on all other columns, so you can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` syntax when processing new data

Setup:

```
create table mytable (
    dog varchar(50),
    cat varchar(50),
    mouse varchar(50),
    lizard varchar(50),
    snake varchar(50),
    created_at timestamp 
        default current_timestamp,
    modified_at timestamp 
        default current_timestamp 
        on update current_timestamp,
    primary key (dog, cat, mouse, lizard, snake)
);
```

Sample `insert`/`update` statement:

```
insert into mytable 
    (dog, cat, mouse, lizard, snake)
values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
on duplicate key update modified_at = current_timestamp
```

Comment: @WestonBushyeager: you are missing the end of the query (`... update dog = values(dog)`